# Show 3 blue boxes where each box has a title, text and button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build this using pure HTML & CSS-

[image]

where we will have 3 blue boxes beside each other, and each box has a title,text & clickable button (which open an external url such as https://stackoverflow.com)..

now i wrote this HTML:-

```
<p style='border-style:solid;background-color:#0096FF;color:white'>
    <div style='text-align:center;background-color:#0096FF;color:white'>Registration</div>
    <div style='text-align:left;background-color:#0096FF;color:white'>Find Our what do you want to renew,replace on your vechcile</div>
</p>
```

but i got this poor layout:-

[image]

any advice how i can achieve the HTML inside the above picture?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flexbox or grid. Here is an exemple of code with flexbox:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="box">
            <H1>My Box 1</H1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum mollitia ab neque quos odio. Deleniti accusamus porro officiis fugit quidem temporibus doloremque, natus tempore beatae unde soluta delectus dicta cumque?</p>
            <button>My button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <H1>My Box 2</H1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta officia ullam asperiores culpa impedit aliquam hic natus? Accusantium esse id accusamus ratione! Sequi quos veritatis vel amet, velit illum incidunt.</p>
            <button>My button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <H1>My Box 3</H1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, eius hic eum vero eveniet minima a nobis pariatur officiis, totam aliquid dicta. Voluptas illum debitis nemo architecto sit nulla voluptate.</p>
            <button>My button</button>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

h1, p{
    text-align: center;
}

.box{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:#0096FF;
    color: white;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

button{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding: 1em;
    color:#0096FF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: 3 boxes]

[here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you have all explications about flexbox.